# Is there a way to register event listeners AFTER rendering the map in React-Leaflet?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

After rendering my map, I may need to change the function registered to an event. Is there a way to do this?

The current solution I've found involved setting a ref and then setting the "container" object directly, but this seems kind of hackish.

What I currently have:

```
() => {
  const test = useRef(null);

  if (test.current)
    test.current.container.onclick = e => console.log("clicked");

  return <Map ref={test} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add onClick in Map component. `react-leaflet` has onClick props

```
<Map onClick={(e) => console.log("clicked")} ref={test} />
```

OR

Use `useEffect` hook in your functional component. It will trigger once rendered.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (test.current)
     test.current.container.onclick = e => console.log("clicked");
}, []);
```

Note: Dont forget to import useEffect.

> import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

Comment: I'm already doing both, I was actually wondering if there was a more eloquent way to bind the event handler rather than accessing the "container" object

Comment: In the First option, u will pass function as props then u r not directly accessing container DOM.